# Can Eclipse hold multiple different 'Compare' windows at the same time?

Tags: eclipse

Like in the topic - is there any default way or any plugin that lets you have multiple 'Compare' windows open and active at the same time? I find it very frustrating that while doing changes to few files at the same time, I can't have active 'Compare' window for each of them, to see my changes/original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compare window in Eclipse is placed inside a normal editor tab.

You can have several editor tabs, including compare windows, visible at the same time. To do this just drag the editor tab (the one on the top with the editor name) to somewhere inside the editor area. The editor area will get split in two, each one displaying one editor.

This works with more than two editors also.

If you find that you need more space for the compare windows because other views take up much space you can maximize the editor area by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> while the editor area has focus.

Example:
[image]

Comment: I'll add, that currently I use a workaround that works if one of compared versions is a local file (not from cvs history but from one of your projects in your workspace).
When comparing local version, you can make any change to it in compare window (make space and delete it afterwards for instance) and simply don't save it. When you compare other file now, it will be opened in a new window (since Eclipse doesn't want to close window with non-saved changes).
It works nicely, but as I said, it doesn't work when you want to compare only historic versions of a file.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `Window -> New Window`, rerun `Team -> Show History` and then compare another file.

Answer (score 1):

Go to preferences -> team -> General Team Preferences.  For me, the "Reuse open compare editors when opening comparisons" was already checked by default.  I unchecked that and now I can have multiple file comparison windows open!  (I'm using Eclipse Oxygen.3a -- 4.7.3a)